# How to iterate through JSON hash with coffeescript

Tags: json, hash, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Coffeescript and I'm having issues resolving an issue. I have a JSON object that is currently stored in a variable. How do I iterate through the keys in the JSON object to display the key name and values associated with it?

```
if client
  result = JSON.parse client
  $.each result, (k, v) ->
    alert k + " is " + v
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
for key, value of result
  console.log "#{key} and #{value}"
```

more in the [docs#loops](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)

Answer (score 1):

```
result = JSON.parse client
     for c in result
        console.log(c.key +"-"+ c.value)
```

it's work!