# Pupulate Dom HTML fom JSON and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript

I'm pretty new to coffee script.

I'm building a widget for [Ubersicht](http://tracesof.net/uebersicht/)

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht), I need to specify a command, an update interval and some style

So far, I have been able to tweak other existing widgets, but I've come to a roadblock when trying to create one of my own.

I want to iterate trhough a JSON array and populate a table.

I have tried following the example found here:

[How to iterate through JSON hash with coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941915/how-to-iterate-through-json-hash-with-coffeescript)

But I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The dom inspector throws an error saying there is an unexpected indent. I've been up all night trying to figure this out. Please help.

```
# ######################
# index.coffee
#######################

refreshFrequency: 5000

style: """
  white1 = rgba(white,1)
  white05 = rgba(white,0.5)
  white02 = rgba(white,0.2)
  black02 = rgba(black,0.2)
  icon-size = 28px

  //bottom 220px + 49
  //right 0px
  overflow hidden

  @font-face
    font-family Helvetica Neue

  .user_data
    color white1
    white-space nowrap
    width 176px
    padding 8px 0
    align-items center
    display flex

  .text, 
    font-size 8pt
    font-weight 200
    color white1
    text-overflow ellipsis


"""

todayfile = '~/Desktop/today.txt'

command: "cat #{todayfile}"

render: -> """

    <table class="user_data text"><br>
    </table>

"""

update: (output, domEl) ->
    dom = $(domEl)
    data = JSON.parse output
    alloc = data?.name?.user_name?.allocated_hours
        for keys, values of data
        text = '<tr><td>' + data.name[i] + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + data.user_name[i] + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + data.allocated_hours[i] + '</td></tr>'
        dom.find(".user_data").innerHTML =
```

And the JSON file

```
{"results":[{"user_id":"63","user_name":"blueboy","name":" (Super Man)","allocated_hours":"7"},{"user_id":"510","user_name":"allblack","name":" (Batman)","allocated_hours":"7"},{"user_id":"418","user_name":"ladyinred","name":" (Wonder Woman)","allocated_hours":"8"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> refreshFrequency: 5000
> ```

This is not how you assign variables:

1. Variable assignment is with `=`, i.e. refreshFrequency = 5000
2. Assigning items in an Object is done with `:`, i.e.:

   ```
   my_object = 
        refreshFrequency: 5000
   ```

You've repeated this error several times ;-) Note that you *also* use `=` for function assignment, so `render: ->` is also wrong and needs to be `render = ->`.

---

The indentation of your `update` function is off:

> ```
> update: (output, domEl) ->
>     dom = $(domEl)
>     data = JSON.parse output
>     alloc = data?.name?.user_name?.allocated_hours
>         for keys, values of data
>         text = '<tr><td>' + data.name[i] + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + data.user_name[i] + '</td></tr>' + '<tr><td>' + data.allocated_hours[i] + '</td></tr>'
>     dom.find(".user_data").innerHTML =
> ```

Why is the line `for keys, values of data` on a new indentation level? The *start* of new block should never be on a new indentation level, *only* its contents.

Your script also ends abruptly with `innerHTML =`, which is incorrect.

---

Once I fixed the above errors, the file compiled ;-) This is, of course, no guarantee that it also does what you want ;-) I can't really make sense of the script, as such, and seems more like half a script...

Comment: awesome! That helped a lot. I understand how = assigns values to variables, but for this particular issue, that is just how widgets are made for Ubersicht. I couldn't figure out why the loop didn't need to be indented, but when i compiled to javascript it was really easy to see. Thanks for your help!